# Issues with deeplink with default message

Tags: microsoft-teams

We developed an app for MS Teams that utilizes a bot to interact with users.
One of the cards the bot sends includes a button that opens a chat with another person and fills in a default message. This is the form of the button URL:

`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=someone@email.com&message=Hello`

It used to work well in the past year and in the last couple of weeks, all of the sudden, it seemed to have stopped working. What happens is, that a new chat is opened with the user as expected, but the message is not filled.

After a short investigation, we discovered that when inputting the URL above directly to the URL bar in the browser - it does work, and the default message appears. Moreover - if go and click on the button in the bot - it will now work as expected and fill the default message. This will continue working until we refresh the page - then it stops working again.

Feel free to watch this screen recording demonstrating the issue (sorry for the foreign language in the first 10 seconds ): https://myquestworld-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/roy_myquest_co/EWGmLFZ49r5KlurOsMBeXIYBU1gBmhHmL2n-Cbo144JsOQ?e=2lXKAW

We contacted Office 365 support, and they directed us to this forum. We believe this is a bug in MS Teams, but so far we're not able to get MS to do anything about it.

Does anyone else experience this issue? Anything we can do about it?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: We are also able to repro this issue at our end. It works fine on mobile but not on Web and Desktop. We will check internally and get back to you.

Comment: We raised a bug for the same, we will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Meghana-MSFT - wondering if there are any updates on the matter? It's affecting our apps in production. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Roy Bartal - We currently do not have any updates/ETA to share. We will keep you posted as soon as we get an update from engineering team. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Meghana-MSFT - It's been over a month since the issue was reported- can you at least share if there's any progress or ETA ?

Comment: Hi @Roy Bartal - Apologies, Engineering team has not been able to reproduce the issue, could you please share a fiddler trace at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com. So that team can investigate it. Thanks.